# Launching camera and creating a name for the picture is returning null Intent to onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, uri, onactivityresult

My problem is in this line:

`pictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", createImageFile());`

when i comment it the camera does not return null intent to onActivityResult but when I uncomment it, it sends null to Intent data,but its saving the file with the name i specified.

Here is the code:

Start Camera:

```
private void invokeCamera() {

    // get a file reference
    Uri pictureUri;

        pictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", createImageFile());

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // tell the camera where to save the image.
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);

    // tell the camera to request WRITE permission.
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

Create File:

```
 private File createImageFile() {

    File imageFile;

        // the public picture director
        File picturesDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            String IMGname = Ti.getText().toString() + IMGCounter;

            // put together the directory and the timestamp to make a unique image location.
            imageFile = new File(picturesDirectory,  IMGname + ".jpg");

            Toast.makeText(this,  IMGname + ".jpg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return imageFile;

}
```

onActivityResult code:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode ==  RESULT_OK && data != null){

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Reached REq", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // AddImgToView(data);

        }else if(requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST){

            AddImgToView(data);

        }



    }else{

        Toast.makeText(this, "Op 2"+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

Manifest Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!--Required Permissions-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <provider
        android:authorities="company.com.retrofit.provider"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>

    </provider>


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".InsertData"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I'm sure if it will help you, but have you tried to add writing storage permissions to your application?

Comment: @AntonMakov Check the code again I added the Manifest,My problem is with the pictureUri part.When i remove it,the code works,when i add it,it keeps sending null data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the default Android camera sends data when you are sending a thumbnail, but when you use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` it sends null and I have to use the URI I specified.

Answer (score 0):

Check for writing to external storage permission , implement dynamic permission model, I see nothing wrong in the code otherwise

Comment: Ok so the pictureUri is not null i added a toast to see if it has something or not,and it has a location of the file,but yet it is still returning null,when i remove the pictureURI it works fine